# Integration between Salesforce and Peoplesoft

Tags: integration

I need help regarding integration between salesforce and People soft.

We are looking to do Bi directional integration between salesforce and People soft.

Question:

To login into salesforce from peoplesoft.I can give enterprise Wsdl to People soft developer. Is that correct? and then he can use login API to login into salesforce. Is this known as soap or rest Api? If it is Soap, can I still give enterprise WSDl which he can use to login into salesforce and then I can create rest based web services using Apex which he can use to post, create or update data in salesforce.

Can we use enterprise WSDL and rest based Api's  together to update, create records in salesforce or not?

Instead of using Enterprise WSDl If I only use Rest based Api's. Do we have to implement OAuth so that people soft when trying to connect to salesforce get's authorization from salesforce.

We are not going to use any third party tool for accomplishing this.

Can somebody please advise with right information?

Answer (score 3):

The Enterprise WSDL is a SOAP API. You can use the login method in the SOAP API to retrieve a Session Id and then use that session Id in REST calls. Something like this in your code would accomplish that:

```
Request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + sessionId);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel,So I can create rest based web services in salesforce using Apex and give the URL of the web service to the peoplesoft guy who will use it to post data to the rest service.Webservice will insert or update data in salesforce.Is that correct?Following your suggestion ,I think I can avoid Oauth ,Is that correct?.So based on some workflow in peoplsoft,salesforce login Api will be called automaticaly and then rest services will be called which in turn will post data in salesforce.Daniel,Do u think I am heading in the right direction?.

Comment: You don't need to create a REST based web service with Apex unless you need to perform logic. If you are doing an integration to push changes, I would think the standard API would suffice. For example, here's how you can [create a record.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm)